# Loop through all the folders to search the latest modified file

Tags: java, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

If you check the image below, I have a google bucket containing 3 folders and each folder contains the same files `Test_1.csv` and `Test_2.csv`. These 2 files will be taken as input in my dataflow pipeline.

[image]

**The scenario is** : There are many users who will first put the `Test_1.csv` and `Test_2.csv` files in any folder they want (the old files will be replaced) then execute the program . The concern is when user1 put the latest `Test_1.csv` and `Test_2.csv` in any folder then the program should check all the folders and fetch only the last modified files. Likewise when user2 puts the latest files and excutes the program then the program should check all the folders and fetch only the last modified files.

I can check the last modified file in a folder with below code :

```
private File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath){
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
    return null;
}

File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
   if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
       lastModifiedFile = files[i];
   }
}
return lastModifiedFile; }
```

How can I loop through all the folders in search of latest modified file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you're looking to find both `Test_1.csv` *and* `Test_2.csv`?

Pass in the root folder, and iterate recursively through the folders to find the two files:

```
public static File Test1;
public static File Test2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("\\\\your\\file\\path");
    searchFiles(file);
    System.out.println(Test1);
    System.out.println(Test2);
}

public static void searchFiles(File directory) {
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        File[] subDirectories = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : subDirectories) {
            searchFiles(file);
        }
    } else {
        if (Test1 == null) {
            if (directory.getName().contains("Test_1")) {
                Test1 = directory;
            }
        }
        if (Test2 == null) {
            if (directory.getName().contains("Test_2")) {
                Test2 = directory;
            }
        }
        if (directory.getName().contains("Test_1") && directory.lastModified() > Test1.lastModified()) {
            Test1 = directory;
        }
        if (directory.getName().contains("Test_2") && directory.lastModified() > Test2.lastModified()) {
            Test2 = directory;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm trying to find both the files , but what if the number of folders are not 3 and it varies from time to time ? It means I can also have Folder_4 or Folder_5.

Comment: Can you just use `.contains("Folder")` or whatever part of the name is required? i.e. without the number.

Comment: It means contains("Test_2") folder should be replaced by contains("Folder") . Right ?

Comment: @NageshSinghChauhan well actually ignore that, it won't work. Are you just looking for the last 2 modified files, regardless of the name?

Comment: Test_1.csv and Test_2.csv will remain the same in all the folders. The requirement is , the user will execute the program only after he puts latest Test_1.csv and Test_2.csv in any folder. The program should iterate over all the existing folders and fetch only the latest modified files.

Comment: even if Test_1 and Test_2 are **not** the latest files?

Comment: see, for example all the folders having both these 2 files Test_1 and Test_2, when a new user puts updated files the previous ones will be overwritten, then the user executes the program, the program should check all the folders and pick only the latest files.

Comment: I may have misread some of what you were saying. The code above will work no matter how many folders you have.

Comment: I have executed the code in my local system and on executing it prints 2 times null(obviously). How can I print the content of the file in the console ?